How to determine number of isomorphic trees, and how to draw them?
The question is
"How many nonisomorphic spanning trees does each of these simple graphs have? Draw them. a) K3
b) K4
c) K5"
I found that there is only one nonisomorphic tree for K3, but I can't seem to figure out many there are for the other two. How would I find these, and how would I draw them?
For further context, here is what I've found so far:


Your post is too much of a bare problem statement without much context. Please describe better the work you have already done, so as to provide more context and avoid writing a no-clue question. For example, perhaps you already do know of at least one spanning tree for $K_4$, in which case you can edit your post to include that information.

I have made an edit showing my current information. Would this do?

Pick something that you know doesn't change with a graph isomorphism. For example, the number of leaves (vertices with degree $1$) must be equal between two isomorphic graphs. So we can break the problem down by asking how many non-isomorphic trees there are with $p$ leaves, where $p$ ranges over all possible values. We can then add these values, because we're not double counting.

Does it help if you rephrase the problem as "how many nonisomorphic trees are there with $n$ vertices"? (Do you see why that's equivalent?) Also, I think that two of the graphs you've drawn for b) are isomorphic.

I added another one. Is that one isomorphic, or are there only two graphs I can draw?

I am going to assume that this is an introductory graph theory class, and thus they are expecting you to mostly "brute force" your way to the answer. What I would recommend is focusing on the degrees of the vertices. For example, both of the graphs you have found so far have two degree one vertices (a tree will always have at least two degree one vertices) and the rest are degree two vertices. Can you make a tree with a degree 3 vertex?

I made an edit to my answer, did I manage to make one of my graphs on degree vertex 3? Or am I misunderstanding?

Yes, the third most graph has a vertex of degree 3! Can a tree in K4 have two vertices of degree 3? Can it have a vertex of degree 4 or more? Then repeat the process for K5.
Also, unrelated to the degree 3 tree, ask yourself if your two left-most trees are really different. Remember that two graphs are isomorphic if you can map the vertices of one graph to the other such that the edges are preserved.
